# What is causing "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1, 166)"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I've tried to adapt code for recognising numbers from mnist to a text generation task. I'm getting a value error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1, 166)
```

How do I make the final layer fit this output shape?

I've divided some text data into sentences. `x_train` and `x_test` are messy sentences created with OCR software, `y_train` and `y_test` are the same sentences, but with manually proof read and corrected. I want to train the model to see common mistakes and correct them.

I've looked for solutions to this problem on here and other sites. The most common solution that seems to work for people is using `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'`, but I'm already using this.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
# Import test and train sets
test_in = open("test.pkl", "rb")
test_set = pickle.load(test_in)
train_in = open("train.pkl", "rb")
train_set = pickle.load(train_in)
x_test, y_test = test_set[0], test_set[1]
x_train, y_train = train_set[0], train_set[1]

# Map all characters in both sets
chars = sorted(list(set("".join(x_train + y_train + x_test + y_test))))
chardict = dict((c, i + 1) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
rchardict = dict((i + 1, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

# Encode lists using mapping
temp_list = list()
for gloss in x_test:
    encoded_gloss = [chardict[char] for char in gloss]
    temp_list.append(encoded_gloss)
x_test = temp_list
temp_list = list()
for gloss in y_test:
    encoded_gloss = [chardict[char] for char in gloss]
    temp_list.append(encoded_gloss)
y_test = temp_list
temp_list = list()
for gloss in x_train:
    encoded_gloss = [chardict[char] for char in gloss]
    temp_list.append(encoded_gloss)
x_train = temp_list
temp_list = list()
for gloss in y_train:
    encoded_gloss = [chardict[char] for char in gloss]
    temp_list.append(encoded_gloss)
y_train = temp_list

# Pad all sentences
max_len = max([len(x) for x in x_train + y_train + x_test + y_test])
x_test = np.array(pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=max_len, padding='post'))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], 1, x_test.shape[1]))
y_test = np.array(pad_sequences(y_test, maxlen=max_len, padding='post'))
y_test = np.reshape(y_test, (y_test.shape[0], 1, y_test.shape[1]))
x_train = np.array(pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=max_len, padding='post'))
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
y_train = np.array(pad_sequences(y_train, maxlen=max_len, padding='post'))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (y_train.shape[0], 1, y_train.shape[1]))

# Normalise to improve training speed
x_test = x_test/37.0
x_train = x_train/37.0

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x_test.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
opt = Adam(lr=1e-3, decay=1e-5)

# Compile and fit the model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_test, y_test, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_train, y_train))
```

I'd like to be able to train the model so that I can try it on unseen sentences and see if it's overfitting, but I can't get past this roadblock.

Edit to include full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adrian/PycharmProjects/WurzburgGlossParser/Rough Work.py", line 80, in <module>
    model.fit(x_test[:30], y_test[:30], epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test[30:40], y_test[30:40]))
  File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 1, 166)
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback error? Also are you able to debug the code in an IDE that will help you tremendously. The error is pointing to unexpected data being sent around.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the dimension of size `1` from your labels:

```py
y_test = np.squeeze(y_test, axis=1)
y_train = np.squeeze(y_train, axis=1)
```

Comment: I included this after normalisation and got `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (166,)`. Where should this code be put to fix the error?

Comment: @AdeDoyle Could you add to your question the shapes of the `x_train`, `y_train`, `x_test`, `y_test` immediately before you call `model.fit()` (e.g. `x_train.shape`)? And without applying the code in my answer. This way it will be much easier for me to help you.

Comment: @Vlad I can add it to the question if you like, but it's the same as what's in the traceback report. x_train and y_train =  (30, 1, 166) and x_test and y_test = (10, 1, 166). That's 30 or 10 sentences of one row of 166 characters. This may not be the best way to format it, so feel free to tell me if I could do this better. I'm very new to ML.

Comment: Embedded sentences, right? Not the actual characters of type `str`. + Yes, please post here both `x_train` and `y_train`. e.g. Maybe you should convert labels to one-hot encoding so I need to see the shapes of both labels and data. Thanks.

Comment: In one of the `# Encode lists using mapping` step above I encode the sentences so that each character is represented as an int between 1 and 37, but they're not one-hot encoded. Both the labels and the training data are the same. The code above includes everything I've done to edit the sentences before fitting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192491/discussion-between-vlad-and-adedoyle).